# How to install php-gd on Mac OS X 10.6.x

Tags: php, mac-osx

Snow Leopard does not comes with php-gd module by default. How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

The version of PHP distributed with Snow Leopard was compiled with GD. ([source](http://www.brandonsavage.net/first-glance-apples-snow-leopard/)) Can you run phpinfo() and tell me if the GD module appears in the output? I'm on 10.6.7, and phpinfo() reports that GD support is enabled: "bundled (2.0.34 compatible)".

Comment: GD is shown as enabled but didn't work. I went for: http://php-osx.liip.ch/